# Secure (P2P) Client/Company File Sharing

Tags: webserver, file-encryption, server, file-upload, p2p

my small web design company currently uses a cloud storage service to collaborate with our clients and I would like an easier (and more secure) way for files to be transferred-in and stored.

The only reason we use cloud storage is because most of those services have cross-platform mobile applications so we tell our clients to upload their files to our account through the convenience of such apps. However, I am not comfortable with these files being stored on a random server somewhere (unknown) in the "cloud" owned and accessible by people (unknown) in parts; unknown.

After a ton of research I ran into "BitTorrent Sync" which is literally everything I want. Files can comes in (to our central location; our office) and mobile apps exist for it so our clients can easily send us their files from most of their devices. However, is it secure? Is there a better solution and/or perhaps an optimal set-up?

All files transferred-in do not contain sensitive information and/or copyrighted (or illegal) content. However, they lose value if obtained without authorization. Especially if pirated. Imagine you spend two years writing a book and we are the publishing company. Imagine 95% of your work is stolen prior it is complete/polished/published prior going on shelves for sale. Make sense? We can't afford that!

That said, I need a set-up that is 100% secure and operates like BitTorrent Sync. I guess that's called P2P? I clearly have no programming or server experience/knowledge. I tried my best to learn and it does not register (respect to everyone in such fields).

Anyway, I am in need of a simple (but highly secure) solution for my clients to drop files to us. Cross-platform ways for them to send files is as important as the security + it would nice if the files are restricted to anyone that is not on our client list.

My question is... what can or should I do to accomplish this? Can a system be created where we continue to use BitTorrent Sync but on a secured device or dedicated/virtual server? Are their a ton of existing software that can easily accomplish this?

All feedback appreciated in advance. Thank you!

Comment: do you need P2P? are your clients sharing with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution has been in place for many years. It's called SFTP. It's a direct client-to-server connection with an encrypted channel for upload. The technology is so old that many, many clients exists and even some browsers will allow you to connect to SFTP servers.

All you need to do is to set up a small server on your end with access to the Internet. You provide the login details to your clients and they can upload to their heart's content.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for the quick reply. Is there any sort of cross-platform mobile applications that allow SFTP connections to my server? Also, if so, would uploading through an app make things vulnerable? Honestly, I just need something super simple with a GUI for my clients to log-in and upload. Perhaps a branded app even. But for now, something general will do.

Comment: There are many apps that can do SFTP, and building your own STFP client is pretty easy (old protocol).